# git is showing changes in files that are already added to gitignore?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have already added log2 folder and main.js file to .gitignore as can be seen in the screenshot.

But even after executing `git rm --cached .-r` I could still see git is detecting changes in main.js and files inside log2 folder.

How come?

[image]

Comment: Because `.gitignore` was also removed.

Comment: @ElpieKay I am not sure what you mean by that. Is it necessary for .gitignore to be committed in order for it to work? Even if that's the case, it is still not working. I executed `git rm --cached .-r` then `git add .gitignore` then `git commit -m "added gitignore` and still I could see that main.js and files inside log2 are showing up when I change something there.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. What does `cat .gitignore` print?

Comment: @ElpieKay it prints `log2/ 
main.js`

Comment: The usual problem with these is a gitignore coded in UTF-16. Save it as UTF-8. UTF-16 is redundant bloat at this point, larding new code just to make utf-16 not look bad would just be compounding the waste.

Comment: @jthill That was it. Why don't you post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I had the same issue today, described here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64728721/git-is-ignoring-gitignore-file-under-windows-10 , the solution worked for me too !

Comment: @mounaim all hail stackoverflow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual problem with these is a gitignore coded in UTF-16. Save it as UTF-8. UTF-16 is redundant bloat at this point, larding new code just to make utf-16 not look bad would just be compounding the waste.