# Git is ignoring gitignore file under Windows 10

Tags: python, git, windows-10, gitignore

Git is ignoring the folders in .gitignore file.
Here is my .gitignore : (env is a folder generated by venv in Python )

```
#folders
env/**
pdfs/**


# files

#source files
/timeformat.py
/pdfreader.py
```

I already did : `git rm -r --cached .` then `git add .` but it's adding all the files under env/Lib/site-packages
What is the problem ?

**EDIT :**

here is my directory structure :

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you try 
`env/*
pdfs/*
`
basically with just single *

Comment: Is your `.gitignore` called exactly `.gitignore` and located in the root of your repository?

Comment: @bk2204 I added a screenshot of my folder structure

Comment: Can you check at the command line?  The graphical interface often hides extensions like `.txt` which mean that the file name is different from the one that Git is looking for.

Comment: @bk2204 yeah I checked and added a screen for that too in the question, it is .gitignore actually

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64728395/1256452), posted about the same time as your own question.

Comment: @torek it works !! Thank you man !! why is this the case ?? I changed the encodign of the file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and it worked !! that was very frustrating, spent the whole day debugging this issue :/

Comment: [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is a terrible file format and Git does not use it. Windows, of course, uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your gitignore from

```
#folders
env/**
pdfs/**
```

to:

```
#folders
env/*
pdfs/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be the **`.gitignore`** file and env folder not present at same level in directory structure.

You can start with **`**/dir`** to ignore the **dir folder** inside any directory.

In your case:

```
**/env/
```

Comment: they are at the same level

Comment: Can you try it with `**/env/` ?

Answer (score 0):

change env/** to env /*
It did the job for me